# 'attempt to subtract with overflow' ¿Como puedo arreglar este error en mi codigo?

Tags: rust

Estaba experimentando con strings y la libreria `std::io`, por lo que intenté hacer un programa que imprimiera en pantalla uno por uno todos los caracteres de una cadena:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    
let mut expresion = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut expresion)
        .expect("No se pudo leer la linea");

    if expresion.trim() == "exit" {
        print!("el plan ha fallado con exito");
    }

    for i in 0..expresion.len(){
        println!("{}", &expresion[i-1..i] );
    }
}
```

No me sale ningun error de sintaxis, el programa compila sin problema, pero en tiempo de ejecucion, me sale el siguiente error:

> "thread 'main' panicked at 'attempt to subtract with overflow', src/main.rs:16:35"

Comment: no sé si entendí bien pero cambiaría: &expresion[i-1..i] por :println!("{}",&expresion[i..i+1]); ya que el el slice comenzaría en el índice dado por el for y terminaría en el mismo más 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He aquí un mes mas tarde con la respuesta de mi propia pregunta, bueno el problema de mi codigo residia aquí:

```
    for i in 0..expresion.len(){
        println!("{}", &expresion[i-1..i] );
    }
```

En el primer ciclo, i toma el valor de 0 por lo tanto &expresion[i-1..i] lo que daria lugar a &expresion[-1..1] que en rust es absolutamente invalido, la mejor forma de solucionar eso es cambiando el *for* de la siguiente manera:

```
    for i in 1..expresion.len(){
        println!("{}", &expresion[i-1..i] );
    }
```

Comment: o sea una variante de lo que puse en mi comentario

Comment: Pues si, pero tu comentario me abria dado error al final del bucle por que si el rango es de 0..expresion cuando i = expresion.len() el rango quedaria &expresion[expresion.len()..expresion.len() + 1], que no es posible de representar porque expresion no tiene mas elementos despues de su ultimo elemento